# FLUTTER BLOC - Infinite List and Filter features

Tags: flutter, api, filter, bloc

I am learning Bloc state management in Flutter and trying to apply infinite list and filter functions on a screen. However, it seems complicated to me. Do you have any idea how I should handle them?

API Endpoint for getting records:

```
POST http://example.com/api/recruitment_requests/filter?limit={number}&page={number}
```

body:

```
{
    "filterBody": [],
    "searchString": "", 
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": ""
}
```

Infinite List:

> https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @targiasld, I just show you the screen flow and the api endpoint. I can't show the code here because it has a lot of lines and also for security.